# Trying to put 2 images to over lap one another

Tags: python, image, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I have two pictures that I need to put together as one. The first one is about a beach with the ocean. The second picture is a cactus with a very bright green screen behind it. I need to find a way to tune down the green screen in the cactus picture so that I can place it over the beach picture and make it look like there is a cactus at the beach. I can change the pixel colors but I can not seem to take out the bright green screen color of the cactus picture. I can also put both pictures together but the green screen of the cactus picture over writes the coloring of the beach picture. Could any please help show me how to tune down the green pixels of  the cactus picture or  get rid of the green screen part?
Here is the code that I am working with. It's in the google docs. I am at a lost.
here is a link to see what I need to do. The last picture is how it should look

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZYrigN1LXSMq3_llc6eimZqBh2R9ZVeBmmxSUx63__E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far. Also, please link to original images through imgur instead of Google Drive links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to change (r, g, b) value for best mask. You can use range also. Check this out.

```
from PIL import Image  
from PIL import ImageFilter  
import os  
 
im1 = Image.open('beach.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('cactus.jpg')
back_im = im1.copy()

for filename in os.listdir("."): 
    if filename[-3:] == "jpg":  
        img = Image.open(filename)  
        img = img.convert("RGBA")  
        pixdata = img.load()  
        for y in range(img.size[1]):  
            for x in range(img.size[0]):  
                r, g, b, a = img.getpixel((x, y))  
                if (r == 76) and (g == 244) and (b == 24):  
                    pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 0)  
                if r == 0 and g == 0 and b == 0:  
                    pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 0)  

        img2 = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=1)) 
        back_im.paste(img2,mask=img2)
        back_im.save('filename.jpg')
```